# Change Registry Key Permissions Access Control List using only Command Prompt

Tags: windows, scripting, windows-registry, windows-command-prompt, batch

I am trying to change the Access Control permissions on a specific registry key i'm generating using a batch file.  I try using regini.exe to pull the configuration from a .ini file and run into issues.

**I keep getting this error:**

```
    Z:\EM\Pre>regini.exe RegistryPermissions.ini 
    REGINI: CreateKey (\HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\Software\E) relative to handle (000000000) failed - 161
    REGINI: Failed to load from file 'RegistryPermissions.ini' (161)
```

**This is the contents of my .ini file RegistryPermissions.ini:**

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\Software\E [1 7]
```

**This is the batch script i'm writing to solve a problem:**

```
@echo off
:: ==========================================
:: Set E Key
:: ==========================================
:: Date   : 11 October 2019
:: Author : 
:: Modified Date: 
:: Modified By: 
:: 
:: Script Details:
:: --------------
::  This script will:
::  + add the E Registry key to HKCC\Software
::  + set the Key permissions to allow "Everyone" full control
::  + reboot PC
:: ===========================================


::***************************************************************
:: Add E Registry Key to HKCC\Software                  *
::***************************************************************
REG ADD HKCC\Software\E

::***************************************************************
:: Set the Key to permissions to allow Everyone full control    *
::***************************************************************
=====This is where I need help=====


::***************************************************************
:: Reboot PC                            *
::***************************************************************



goto end

:end
```

I have removed some unnecessary sections of the script.
The important part is changing the permissions on a registry key, with cmd.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG_(HKCC)) `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG` is an alias to the path

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Hardware Profiles\Current
```

So try

```
\registry\machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Hardware Profiles\Current\Software\E [1 7]
```

and see if that works better.

---

If it still doesn't work, you might like to try another technique; registry permissions can be modified in Powershell, for example, or you can use the subinacl tool from Microsoft or various third-party tools.

(I found [some suggestions here](https://eddiejackson.net/wp/?p=5711) that might or might not be helpful.)

Answer (score 0):

Run As Admin:

yourtext.txt (make sure that the Key itself has no []
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\YourPath [1]

and than:
Regini -m \%COMPUTERNAME% %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\DESKTOP\yourtext.txt